# OneNote page content preAuthenticated not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I am getting OneNote Page content using:

```
/v1.0/sites/{0}/onenote/pages/{1}/content?preAuthenticated=true
```

My understanding of the preAuthenticated option is that the output HTML should provide public URLs for images. It looks like public URLs are being provided when I inspect the page HTML (they look different to normal), but they are not accessible. I get a 401 error in chrome's console, and if I follow the public URL it returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "47ccaf06-da94-4db6-8385-61cb81a1379f",
      "date": "2018-04-09T03:35:44"
    }
  }
}
```

The html displays fine, so the /content call appears to work, but just no images

The call is made on-the-fly using an ajax web service called by javascript on my page. The web service gets the token and authenticates the api call. As it's live, there should be no way that the 1-hour timeout has been reached

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/4339/files

They removed the support for it. I'm in same boat. I want the public url and can't get it.